# Switch from UIViewController to other ViewController which is inside navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the following views:

`TabBarController` includes (`MapViewController`, `NavigationController`)
Navigation Controller includes the `DetailViewController` which is needed to switch to.
Code below is used in the `MapViewController`.

Right now my code:

```
    let eventDetailViewController : EventDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventDetail") as EventDetailViewController
    eventDetailViewController.event = event
    self.showViewController(eventDetailViewController, sender: self)
```

This works, but the navigation controller is no where insight (I cannot go to `firstviewcontroller` for example).

How to fire this code via the navigation controller?

Below is a screenshot of the storyboard. From left to right: TabbarController -> NavigationController and MapController. NavigationController -> EventController. The most righter view is the EventDetailView
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Is the EventDetailViewController the root view controller of the navigation controller?

Comment: Can you clarify 1) what is the rootViewController of the navigation Controller? 2) where does 'firstViewController' come into the picture? 3) exactly where/how do you want to show the eventDetailViewController?  Do you want it 'pushed' onto the navigation controller which is in a separate tab of the tabBarController?  Or displayed (in a navigation controller) modally over the top of the MapView?

Comment: Explaining this issue spins my head. From Navigationcontroller on: NavigationController's rootViewController is called EventController. Event controller has a tableview from which it shows the detailviewcontroller when clicked on a cell. I want the view to be pushed onto the navigation controller. Sorry for the confusion, I am pretty confused myself.

Comment: Try the following in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function: `self.navigationController.pushViewController(eventDetailViewController, animated: YES)` (with the same two first lines as you use above)

Comment: I need to perform this pushing from the MapController which is included in the tabbar controller. I think that's what is the real issue. It already works in the didselectrow... function . Sorry for the confusion again!

Comment: Please take a screenshot of your storyboard and add it to the question.

Comment: Done that. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Can someone check the screenshot? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from your MapView, `self.tabBarController` will point to the tabBarController.  It looks from your storyboard like the Navigation Controller is the first tab, so will be at index 0 in the tabBarController's `viewControllers` property.  So you should be able to do the following:

```
let eventDetailViewController : EventDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventDetail") as EventDetailViewController
eventDetailViewController.event = event
let navController : UINavigationController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
navController.pushViewController(eventDetailViewController, animated:YES)
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

I'm still learning Swift, so you may have to sort some optionals/unwrapping out - but I hope you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solved my problem. Sometimes I needed to add a ? but besides that; this works!